# Android Virtual Device without virtualization hardware support?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, virtualization, amd-processor, avd-manager

I am using ACER Aspire E5-553G-F1J2 with AMD Fx9800p processor. My computer's BIOS don't have feature to enable virtualization. So can in run Android emulator without hardware virtualization VT-x or AMD-V ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Intel based images without virtualization enabled and IntelHAXM installed. but you can use ARM images which does not requires hardware virtualization.

To run ARM images:

1. Open AVD manager.
2. Create a new 'Virtual Device' or 'Duplicate' existing image
3. Choose arm* images
4. Continue with the wizard.
5. Run!

**Note : ARM images are available only till API level 25 only and might be slow, have patience.. Cheers :)**